# How do I fix a partition i made installing Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

So I went to Install Ubuntu 12 on my toshiba laptop. I accidently resized my windows 7 partition to 60 GB and Gave Ubuntu 241 GB of Space. I wanted to Have Ubuntu as 60gb and Have the Remaining space for windows 7. How Can I fix the Mistake I made?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **resize2fs** command to a ext4 filesystem, even if it's your root partition:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

[Here you find](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/increase_the_size_of_an_ext2_ext3_or_ext4_filesystem.html) a tutorial step by step!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to get a live cd/usb of ubuntu or gparted bootable media.

Below are steps for ubuntu live disk

- Boot with it
- install `gparted` from the software center.
- Now open `gparted` from dash.
- Select your ubuntu installation and click on resize button. (The button with an arrow in front of stick.)
- Then drag right boundary of ubuntu partition size to desired size.
- Click on "Resize/move".
- Click on unallocated space, select new , follow the wizard and format with ntfs.

[Here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/01/shrink-resize-ubuntu-hard-disk-with-gparted/) is a tutorial for it using gparted iso. The steps are identical.

Comment: Ok its me again. So i Successfully uninstalled ubuntu, fixed my partition , adjusted my mbr or boot file, and now im trying to reclaim my 241gb of unused free space. The problem im having now is when i look at my repartitioned drives my windows 7 c:/ folder still only says 60 gb and am unable to extend my c:/ drive back to its full size .

Comment: why not make an extended drive? Expanding C: is not possible because ubuntu is in between. I would suggest in disk management of windows, right click on unallocated space and create an extended partition. In this way you won't loose any data in case of OS re installation of either win 7 or ubuntu. This partition can be accessed by both OS.

Answer (score 1):

"*... my windows 7 c:/ folder still only says 60 gb and [I] am unable to extend my `c:/` drive back to its full size*"

It is possible that the 241 (or so) GB of unused free space is part of an [*Extended (or logical) partition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#PC_partition_types). (Or vice-versa, Windows could be in a *logical partition* and the free space is outside and can't be used.

Either way this would prevent you from using the unallocated space to expand your Windows partition.

I would prefer to know what your current partitions are before suggesting how to modify them.

One possible way to provide this information would be to use a tool name `boot-repair` after booting up *Try Ubuntu* with a Live CD. The tool would collect a Bootinfo Summary containing your current partition information and write it to a pastebin on the Internet.

I tried to describe how to do this in [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/129842/52923) to another question.

If you use my suggestion above, please be sure to *remember* the URL of the pastebin and to add it to your question.