# Unable to boot Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu to MacBook with OS X & Windows 7 (bootcamp)

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows-7, macbook, dual-boot

I had Lion OSX partitioned with Windows 7 using BootCamp [on my MacBook].

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu last night and it went well. Until this morning when I tried to boot up Windows 7 and it took me to Ubuntu instead.

I saw the windows 7 loader so I clicked on that. It brought me to a black screen with a white cursor in the top left. This is what windows usually looks like when it boots but this time it just stayed on the black screen.

I also tried holding option and choosing the windows drive manually but it brought me back to Ubuntu. I think what happened was that I did not click on the Windows 7 loader when installing Ubuntu 12.04 last night.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you still boot Lion OS X? When you refer to "*choosing the windows **drive** manually*" did you mean "*partition*"? (Do you have just one disk drive? Or is Windows installed on an (external) drive?)

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have more detailed information about how your GRUB and Windows boot configuration are currently setup on your MacBook. I suggest you try this:

- Boot into the Ubuntu you installed on your MacBook.
- Create a Bootinfo Summary using the [**boot_info_script**](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/).
- Copy the summary into a pastebin (For example, http://paste.ubuntu.com).
- Edit your question to include the link to the pastebin containing the summary.

An alternative way to accomplish the same thing would be to install and run a utility named [**Boot-Repair tool**](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It will create a bootinfo summary and post it to a pastebin for you "automatically" in one step.

I have another answer which describes how to do this. Here is a link to that answer:
[**How to use boot-repair to provide a "Bootinfo Summary"**](https://askubuntu.com/a/129842/52923)

- **Note:**
  The Boot-Repair tool also has a button to perform a <kbd>Recommended repair</kbd>. Since this is a Mac with a [*hybrid MBR*](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html), I would caution against doing that until you have a better understanding of just what the problem is.
  *My advice is to first get the bootinfo summary and wait until you have looked at it before attempting to fix this with Boot-Repair.*