# When upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10, after rebooting, Ubuntu won't load when selected from boot menu

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

I just upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. I followed the upgrade instructions on Ubuntu's website, and followed all onscreen instructions. My problem is, when I select Ubuntu from the boot menu, it gives me a screen that says at the top:

> "GRUB4DOS 0.4.5b 2011-11-27, Mem: 639K/1010M/0M, End: 3554C0 [ Minimal
>   BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first wors, TAB lists
>   possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
>   completions of a device/filename.] grub>"

How do I go about booting Ubuntu from this screen?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the same error message. I solved the problem using easyBCD on Windows 7 following the instructions in this post: [How can I add an entry for Ubuntu to the Windows 7 boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139966/how-can-i-add-an-entry-for-ubuntu-to-the-windows-7-boot-menu)

Comment: Can you please summarize the instructions in your link?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to attempt the upgrade again. I created a handy step-by-step screenshot guide that lays out all the steps as precisely as possible. Check it out and let me know if it helps!

http://www.maknesium.de/guide-upgrade-ubuntu-from-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-to-12-10-quantal-quetzal