# After installing Ubuntu 13.04 and running boot-repair, Ubuntu fails to load, gets stuck with a blank screen

Tags: 13.04, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad with Windows 8 preinstalled with great difficulty. To make it run, I edited the boot command by adding the following line:

```
acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor.
```

I was able to boot once into Ubuntu after running boot-repair. But then subsequent times onwards, I get stuck with a blank screen in spite of giving the above options. I ran boot repair a couple of times more using a live disk and a live USB. It still gets stuck.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6339188/

I've noticed a few things. I've got a lot of partitions on my disk now. There is a partition for Windows 8, a partition for Lenovo backup files, 2 partitions (around 200GB each) for miscellaneous purposes and one more partition for Ubuntu. Everything else, I'm not sure how they've appeared. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Turn off UEFI mode in bios and set it to Legacy mode

Comment: I tried that. But it is still not allowing me. Should i run boot repair once again after doing that?

Comment: I ran boot-repair again, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1.First run this command on ubuntu,to know proper chaining was done or not,

```
sudo os-prober
```

IF it shows like this `/dev/sda1:Windows 8 (loader):Windows:chain`,then proceed to step 2.

2.Run the windows installation disk,select repair option and open the command prompt.Run    the below commands on the displayed command prompt

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

Comment: Should I use a live cd to enter Ubuntu?

Comment: is that you can able to boot ubuntu or not

Comment: I am not able to boot to ubuntu. I can boot to windows though.

Comment: boot into windows.Then download EasyBCD software.Under linux tab set Grub2 as bootloader and add an entry for  ubuntu by locating the partition where ubuntu installed.And also create boot entry for windows partition.

Comment: I downloaded EasyBCD, but I couldnt find any Linux tab as you have mentioned. Is there any tutorial you can point to?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/139966/how-can-i-add-an-entry-for-ubuntu-to-the-windows-7-boot-menu and also add entry for your windows partition.

Comment: I tried that. But it didnt work. Actually, I am getting the grub for Ubuntu. It contains Ubuntu as well as Windows OS for selection, but when I select Ubuntu, it fails to load with the problems I've mentioned.