# Can't boot into Linux Dual Boot. HP goes directly to Windows8

Tags: boot, dual-boot

So... I wanted to mount a virtual environment of Windows 7 on VirtualBox. I found out I had to turn on "Virtualization" on the BIOS. So, I went to the BIOS and enabled Virtualization. Then reboot the computer, it showed some HP repair messages which I accepted, and now It goes directly to Windows 8. Can't find the way to boot into linux.

Comment: Did you try [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) ? Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139966/how-can-i-add-an-entry-for-ubuntu-to-the-windows-7-boot-menu) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but it doesn't work. I get a black screen with white letters saying "Windows failed to start...." :/

Comment: Can you disable virtualization in BIOS and try?

Comment: Tried that, didn't help. Maybe I need to fix GRUB?

Comment: If you have a windows repair disc, use that to repair windows. Then use EasyBCD to add grub entry for ubuntu.

Comment: Windows works correctly. I just installed EasyBCD and followed the tutorial you suggested but it didn't work. ... how do I add a grub entry for ubuntu?

Comment: You mean you still can not get an option to boot ubuntu and it directly goes to Windows 8?

Comment: Also, does your laptop come with win8 pre-installed in UEFI-mode? If yes and you installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode, there could be problem (and EasyBCD will not be useful).

Comment: Thanks Ron, yes, it used to go directly to Windows 8. I solved it using boot-repair on a live usb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me was installing [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on a USB and booting from it. I found out that whenever I make a change in the BIOS and "Exit and save changes", I'd lose access to Ubuntu, looks like Windows "fixes" the boot and then I can't access GRUB.