# can't access ubuntu after :"sudo lilo -m /dev/sda mbr"?

Tags: dual-boot

I have a dual boot system (windows 7 + Ubuntu 14.04)
at first I could choose which OS I want to login using grub menu
after that I wanted to recover my windows 7 using the recovery partition (hp-pavilion g6) & I couldn't do it.
so I read on the Internet to fix the MBR using the terminal command:
"sudo lilo -m /dev/sda MBR"
Now I can't access my Ubuntu; windows is logging in automatically without any boot menu.
any advice please???

Comment: So, you want to add grub to Windows? Right?

Comment: "I read on the internet" is not usually a reliable source. With that command you replaced the GRUB with the Windows bootloader, that does not see Ubuntu. You have to replace GRUB to lilo again, following maybe an [official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing), not something randomly taken from the internet.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? WUBI or Normally?

Comment: Actually I don't Know about technical issues but yes I think I want to add grub to windows....@SharadGautam

Comment: Thank you for your comment @dadexix86 ... yes it's my fault. I shouldn't have trust anything I read .... and I am grateful for your reference It helped me reinstall grub2 after using EasyBCD too get access to Ubuntu as suggested by Sharad Gautam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a Windows version of Grub2 such as the Neogrub Bootloader. You might wanna try below guide:

> The procedure which has worked for me is outlined below.
>
> Did you perform the install of the NeoGrub bootloader in step (3)? If
> NeoGrub is installed then there will be a `\NST` folder on your `C:`
> drive.
>
> I think this step is sometimes left out of guides for setting up
> EasyBCD.
>
> #### Using EasyBCD to Boot to GRUB from Windows Boot Menu
>
> 1. Start Windows and install the *free* version of [**EasyBCD**](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).
> 2. Open the EasyBCD program and select **Add New Entry** from the sidebar on the left.
> 3. Select the **rightmost** tab, **NeoGrub**, under "*Operating Systems*" and click the <kbd>**Install**</kbd> button.
>
>    [image: screenshot of NeoGrub bootloader install tab]   
>    *Note:*
>    This adds the NeoGrub bootloader code to your `C:\` folder. If the
>    install worked correctly you will see the file `C:\NeoGrub` and the
>    folder `C:\NST`.
> 4. Select the **Linux/BSD** tab. Choose GRUB2 as the type of the entry and, optionally, edit the name of the entry you are about to add
>    to the Windows Boot menu.   
>    [image: EasyBCD Add New Entry for Linux/BSD for GRUB2]   
>    Click the <kbd>**Add Entry**</kbd> button to add
>    an entry to boot Linux (GRUB menu) to the Windows boot menu.
> 5. Select **Edit Boot Menu** from the sidebar to review your changes.    
>    *Note:* You can delete the entry for **NeoGrub Bootloader** if you wish.   You need the bootloader, but you do not need a boot menu entry
>    for it unless you are using it in some other way.
> 6. Save your changes and reboot. When the Windows boot menu appears, select the EasyBCD  entry you added to boot Linux. You should see
>    something similar to the text below.
>
> [image]

Then the GNU GRUB boot menu should appear.

Quoted from https://askubuntu.com/a/140376/408593

Comment: Thank you @SharadGautam for your help ..... EasyBCD helped me to get access to Linux again

Comment: Mention not. Just UPVOTE the answer. Have a great day ahead.

Comment: @SharadGautam - It happens with new users. I upvoted though.