# install Ubuntu and complete wipe out Windows on a machine with a "Windows Boot Manager"

Tags: boot

I just purchased a refurbished Lenovo T420 with pre-installed Windows 7 Professional and am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB flash drive. Apparently, the machine is not using the familiar BIOS but something called "Windows Boot Manager" so I don't see the familiar screen in BIOS where one gets to change the order of boot devices and chose to boot from the USB.

Instead, when I press `F2` during restart (with the USB flash drive inserted), I am presented with the following screen:

[image]

… so I am not allowed to install Ubuntu and my only option is to start Windows 7.

My intention is to **completely wipe out Windows** and install Ubuntu, not have the two of them alongside each other or anything. I've seen references to a program called "EasyBCD" but all of the instructions I've found (e.g. [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/139966/89663)) appear to address situations where people want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

My use case is simpler but it's not clear to me how I should proceed. I clarify again I want to completely wipe-out Windows and their "boot manager".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you save the product key and oem number to resell it if you are wiping it off your machine. Or if you want to reinstall it some day to play games. If you want to resell the machine make a backup of Windows 7.

This [Lenovo support site](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/T420-Cannot-access-BIOS-settings/td-p/582041) states you need to press <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to invoke BIOS setup at the startup. <kbd>F2</kbd> does not work nor does "ThinkVantage" key.

Comment: I pressed F1 but didn't change any settings. Instead, I noticed a note instructing me to press F12 to enter the boot order menu and so I did. I chose to boot from the USB flash drive and I was presented with Unetbootin's menu (try Ubuntu / install Ubuntu etc.) That's because I had used Unetbootin to create a bootable USB flash drive from the Ubuntu ISO image. So at that menu I chose "install Ubuntu" and wiped the entire disk.