# Linux won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm having trouble running Linux, I reserved 200 gb's for linux, and put my ubuntu iso into unetbootin. When I restarted my pc to boot Ubuntu it gave me a missing/corrupted file error which I scanned with windows and windows showed I had no corrupted files. I tried using this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AF1wSPFAq_A) to fix my problem, but my bios version found here (https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/5340?b=1) does not include the settings shown in the video. I haven't been able to work for about a week because I've been also having troubles downloading windows 10 which i need for my new intel hd 4600 drivers so I decided to go for Ubuntu. I'd really appreciate anyone who could help me, thank you.

Comment: You haven't provided release details, but the validation is of your install media, meaning you didn't validate your ISO, or the write to your install media (ie. the step you described as using unetbootin).   Possibly useful : https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Comment: The error you describe (we can be more accurate if you're precise when providing the error) reads like it's the error you'll see in that duplicate post I've linked. In that answer I use errors taken from log files (which are more technical than the error messages that appear on the display; but the corrupted files refer to your installation media, not your installed windows system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using Unetbootin to install Ubuntu, but it didn`t work. So, I decided to install it directly from hard-drive using EasyBCD. It is somewhat difficult to understand until you try it for your own.

If you have some in-depth knowledge about partitions, working with bios type interface, you can check out my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1300287/1158731). I followed these steps, got some errors, but I finally have a dual boot system (Windows 7 & Ubuntu). All the steps and also the solutions to some common errors is mentioned in the answer. Hope my answer helps you to install Ubuntu. Please do comment if this works for you or you get any error.