# Installation taking so long

Tags: boot, mount, grubrescue, unallocated

I installed Ubuntu along side my Linux Mint and removed Linux Mint after that. I didn't use my laptop for a while and when I opened it yesterday. It went into the GRUB rescue menu. I have tried the **set prefix** method but didn't work. Luckily I had the old bootable USB stick and I logged into "Try Ubuntu" and deleted the partitions of the previous Ubuntu OS. In fact, I deleted all of the partitions because I don't have anything important on them and I tried to install from the USB stick.

I have tried nearly 10 times now, but it's not happening. I tried different things like "Minimal installation", with internet, without internet, etc.. None worked. It keeps on loading and I have waited over four hours but nothing happened.

I got "partition creation failed" error a couple of times. I don't have any other desktops to reburn the USB with OS. I am now running on "Try Ubuntu" to even ask this question. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a hardware fault in laptop, possible a bad hard drive.  Would explain grub rescue and trouble with installing.

Comment: You still have the bootable USB. You can get another USB or use a CD (if you have a CD drive) to install Windows 7. If you can bypass grub rescue via bootable ubuntu usb, then you have a chance to install windows 7 (or any other windows version above 7). After installation, if you still get grub rescue, follow [these](https://neosmart.net/wiki/no-such-partition-grub-rescue/#Fix_1_Rebuild_the_BCD) steps to repair bootmgr. Then you can install Ubuntu again from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1300287/1158731).