# USB needed to boot ubuntu after successful installation

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, re-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

[similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142004/cannot-boot-without-usb-stick-after-successful-install?answertab=active#tab-top)

My problem is very much like the problem described in the link.

I have FreeDOS and Ubuntu 12.04. 
When I boot without bootable USB the computer simply proceeds to DOS.
 With USB stick I have to enter ubuntu via BIOS.

I WISH TO REINSTALL Ubuntu. What is the procedure to reinstall ubuntu from ubuntu itself?

Or is there any other solution to the problem?

Comment: Agreed.  There are quite a few of these.  I suspect there is a bug that is causing the USB to be the default install location for the bootloader on certain hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You will find a guide here: [How to Install Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)

Take care: at a certain moment the system will ask you where the bootloader must be installed. Not in the usb of course, but mostly on your hard disk (C drive) - sad1 (mostly).

Comment: the link you gave shows the procedure to install 12.04. But actually i have installed 12.04;the problem is with booting it. I need the bootable USB stick everytime i need to boot ubuntu

Comment: @karthikeyan The reason Julien posted installation instructions is because your symptoms seem to indicate that you did not in fact install Ubuntu to your harddrive, thus you need to actually install it.  It is also possible that you did install Ubuntu but forgot to install a boot loader.  In either case reinstalling and making sure to install the bootloader on the Master Boot Record of your primary hard drive will fix the problem.  When you use a USB to boot you aren't actually booting into an installed Ubuntu, you are just running a "sample version" off of the USB.

Comment: @adempewolff can you please help me now how to reinstall ubuntu?Because when ever i insert the bootable usb stick it takes me to GRUB display to select and enter inti ubuntu; there are no option of installing or reinstalling.

Comment: @adempewolff also how is it possible to add a boot loader now? I am currently typing this from Ubuntu only...

Comment: come to this chat and I will try to help you http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3576/grub-usb-problems

Comment: @adempewolff I am not having enough reputation..but i ran the code you gave - sudo grub-install /dev/sda && sudo update-grub
in the terminal there were a lot that was displayed and it said found freedos on dev/sda1

Comment: @adempewolff is my problem solved? I will restart and try.Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @adempewolff yeah the last statement was done...so there were no error right??

Comment: @adempewolff restarted and found that Ubuntu starts with no problem...THANKS A LOT for the code and help

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda && sudo update-grub
```

Running this code in the terminal solves the problem.

**Thanks a lot** to [Adempewolff](https://askubuntu.com/users/63478/adempewolff).