# Installed Ubuntu sucssessfully, but now won't boot

Tags: boot-failure, windows-vista, usb-creator

My windows Vista had some issues and would freeze after few minutes each time. So decided to install Ubuntu.

First copied the ubuntu .iso file to a USB drive and tried to install - did not work .

Then installed LinuxLive USB creator on another machine, and ran that. Now my USB had the .iso file & other generated files.

Now on Windows Vista machine, change the Boot order to USB and then tried again. Now it took me to the Ubuntu installation page and continued from there. I chose the Erase disk and install Ubuntu option.

Installation was successful. I also noticed a warning message about Low Disk level or something like that, but my machine has 250 gig. So not sure why.

Then restarted the machine, it is not working. I again went and changed the Boot order, but still doesn't work.

Edit: I removed the USB drive before restart. Would that be an issue?

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks so much

Harish

Comment: I was reading another thread and it suggests UBUNTU would have been installed on the USB. And I put in the USB and voila it works. It has been installed on my USB. Do I need to re-install again to put in my laptop. Did I miss anything the first time? – Harish

Comment: I was able to solve it from here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/142004/cannot-boot-without-usb-stick-after-successful-install


It did install on the USB. So I downloaded Boot repair & used:

I used boot-repair, ticking "reinstall grub" as well as "purge and reinstall"


Guess should have search some more before posting. Thanks

Comment: Since you found the answer to your question, you should post it as an answer here. Then (a day later) you can accept your answer. That will clearly indicate (including to people searching) what worked for you, and help others. Answering your own questions (when you know the answer and there isn't already another answer that answers it the same way) is encouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142004/cannot-boot-without-usb-stick-after-successful-install).

It did install on the USB first. So I downloaded Boot repair: I used boot-repair, ticking "reinstall grub" as well as "purge and reinstall".

I did not have to re-install again.

Guess should have search some more before posting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to remove the USB stick after the restart.  After the installation had finished, the computer will shutdown, then you will get a message:

```
Please remove the installation media and close the tray (if any) and then press "Enter"
```

That's when you should remove the USB stick.  Remove the USB stick before that, bad stuff happens.

For the low disk level, maybe Ubuntu cannot read your drive correctly (since your drive can hold 25 copies of Ubuntu).

I would say that you have to reinstall Ubuntu.  Recreate the Ubuntu USB stick using  [Pendrive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) and then follow the steps on the [Ubuntu official website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).  Choose "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" and remove the USB stick **after** Ubuntu told you to.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I was reading another thread and it suggests UBUNTU would have been installed on the USB. And I put in the USB and voila that's true. It has been installed on my USB. Do I need to re-install again to put in my laptop. Did I miss anything the first time?

Comment: You will have to erase and recreate the Ubuntu USB on another computer.  After that install it on your computer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. But I was able to solve it :)