# I can't boot Windows 7 any more after dual booting it with Ubuntu.

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't boot into Win7 since Update to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129784/cant-boot-into-win7-since-update-to-12-04)

I just recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside with my Windows 7, and when I restarted my computer after the installation it doesn't give me a menu asking me whether I want to use Ubuntu or Windows 7, it just goes to Ubuntu.  Please help me because I need to use a lot of programs that I can only use on Windows.

Comment: Check if pressing the ESC key before Ubuntu boots shows you the Grub menu.

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) URL, so that we know your exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post. Follow step by step procedure and have Success in getting entry of windows 7 on grub bootloader . Click [here](http://milindapro.blogspot.in/2012/01/revert-ubuntu-boot-loader-after.html)

Comment: No, this is not the same situation. Your tutorial is when there is no access to Ubuntu, while Philip has no access to Windows.