# No option to boot to windows 3 days after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows, 15.04

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 3 days ago and was able to boot to windows and Ubuntu comfortably but suddenly today there is no option in the boot menu to boot to windows.

Comment: Can you mount the Windows partition and see your Windows files?

Comment: Yes I can @BaileyS

Comment: I am not sure what `boot-repair` does, but have you tried doing `sudo update-grub` ?  If you run it now, what is output to the terminal?   Hopefully something about Windows, and if not... your problem is with grub.cfg.

Answer (score 2):

The excellent [boot-repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) usually sorts out these problems.

If that doesn't fix it the tool can provide more information as to what's going wrong. Details in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129784/cant-boot-into-win7-since-update-to-12-04/129842#129842)

Comment: Already tried boot repair. It states nothing wrong but still can't see windows in boot menu.

Comment: If you use Boot-Repair and choose the second option, you should be able to create a Boot-info file. Can you do this, then post a link to the file? This will give more information about what may be causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But re-installing option worked for me, I didn't even lost any data because the bootable gave me the option to re-install Ubuntu without formatting the data.